# Running an install4j application without a console window

Tags: install4j

I need to launch an install4j application from my own windows service therefore I don't want the terminal windows to be created.

I know that the GUI version launches the console version without a terminal window. How can I duplicate that functionality? Or is there a better way?

Alan

Comment: How do you launch the application? A terminal window will only be created by using cmd.exe to call "start".

Comment: We use ::CreateProcess(NULL, L"Openfired.exe", ... )

Comment: Looking in ProcessExplorer I see that Openfired has spawned a ConHost.exe

Comment: If the launcher is configured as a "console application", I would try to ad another launcher that is configured as a "GUI application". GUI vs console is a static flag in the binary that Windows uses to decide if a console is required.